# Storing multiple pieces of color data in single row of mysql table and querying it

Tags: mysql

I am looking for best way to store records and search them based on the following information:

There are about a million unique posts in a database, each with a `post_id`. Each post has 5 colors associated with it and each color has a `distance` and `percentage` as well.

```
Post
   • Color1 
      • distance
      • percentage
   • Color2
      • distance
      • percentage
   • Color3
      • distance
      • percentage
   • Color4
      • distance
      • percentage
   • Color5
      • distance
      • percentage
```

Each color's "distance" and "percentage" are stored for help sorting the records. Each color is mapped from it's original color hex value to it's closest color hex value in an array of 256 colors. I am doing this so that a search for "ff000" will still match "fe000" and so on.

I don't necessarily need to store hex values. I could store the position of the mapped value from the pre-defined array of 256 colors. The problem I've run into is being able to query for a color, order it by it's score (combination of percentage and distance) and then matching a second, third, fourth, or fifth color.

A search can start with 1 color or it can start with 5. So if I search "ff0000" and "00ff00", the percentage of occurrence between the two colors would be 50% and 50%. Ideally I'd like to be able to set the percentage of color occurrence per color searched. Here's a good example of a color search that does it: http://labs.tineye.com/multicolr/#colors=7e6199,6abbd3;weights=50,50;

---

Initially I stored records in 5 different rows with the same post_id, but recently I have been contemplating a solution that would store the data in a single row per post. The thought was to store up to five of the colors associated with the post, in a hash of sorts based on the position the mapped color occurred in the array of 256 colors. So if "ff0000" appeared in the image, and 3rd in the array, it would be logged in the hash as "001..". The hash would be 256 characters long and only contain 1's or 0's. Initially this seemed like it would work, but if you only search one color, and the hash contains two, you would get a match.

That was just an idea, and I'm not set on trying to make it work. My logic for storing just one row per post is to eliminate "group by", in turn helping keep things fast.

There's got to be a better way to store the data and query it effectively. Any ideas?

Some requirements that are needed:

- Ideally no joins of tables
- Queries need to be fast and utilize indexes as best as they can

Update:

There have been some requests for schemas that I have tried. Here those are:

```
CREATE TABLE `media_has_colors` (
  `media_id` int(9) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `hex` varchar(6) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `map_hex` varchar(6) NOT NULL,
  `percentage` double unsigned NOT NULL,
  `distance` double unsigned NOT NULL,
  `sequence` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`media_id`,`hex`),
  KEY `index_on_hex` (`hex`),
  KEY `index_on_percentage` (`percentage`),
  KEY `index_on_timestamp` (`sequence`),
  KEY `index_on_media_id` (`media_id`),
  KEY `index_on_mapping_distance` (`distance`),
  KEY `index_on_mapping_hex` (`map_hex`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;


CREATE TABLE `media_has_colors` (
  `media_id` int(9) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `color_1_hex` varchar(6) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `color_2_hex` varchar(6) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `color_3_hex` varchar(6) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `color_4_hex` varchar(6) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `color_5_hex` varchar(6) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `color_1_map_hex` varchar(6) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `color_2_map_hex` varchar(6) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `color_3_map_hex` varchar(6) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `color_4_map_hex` varchar(6) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `color_5_map_hex` varchar(6) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `color_1_percent` double unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `color_2_percent` double unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `color_3_percent` double unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `color_4_percent` double unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `color_5_percent` double unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `color_1_distance` double unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `color_2_distance` double unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `color_3_distance` double unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `color_4_distance` double unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `color_5_distance` double unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `sequence` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`media_id`),
  KEY `index_on_timestamp` (`sequence`),
  KEY `index_on_map_hex` (`color_1_map_hex`,`color_2_map_hex`,`color_3_map_hex`,`color_4_map_hex`,`color_5_map_hex`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Here is an example of what I'd expect from results when searching for yellow and red:
[image]

Comment: what's your problem with joins? Joins are great when used properly...

Comment: If you have a solution that uses joins, I'm open to hearing it. However, ideally there would be none.

Comment: ok, on another note, you are trying to retrieve posts based on associated colors, right... (also, please post some of what you've tried)

Comment: This question is rather unclear. Such as why ff000 matches to fe000 and sample data of existing and results from queries. Help us to help you.

Comment: Drew, maybe you missed it this part, "Each color is mapped from it's original color hex value to it's closest color hex value in an array of 256 colors. I am doing this so that a search for "ff000" will still match "fe000" and so on." It's hard to give you results from queries just yet, but I have provided an example of how it should perform, as well as another color search that can be demo'd.  I wouldn't let the mapping of hex colors get you hung up though, that happens in php, not mysql and is just here to help explain my setup.

Comment: I will take a look tomorrow as it is late. In the future @ their name so they get a notification. I randomly made it back here.